# Using Simulated Metrics and AutoLayout fails to Correctly Account for Subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I built a custom `UIView` xib that I am using in a `UIViewController`. The entire view is moved up under the `UINavigationBar`. I used the `Simulated Metrics` to position the view where it should be and used the

*Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > (All views) Reset to Suggested*

But when I navigate to that view, the view is misplaced Like So:

[image]

**Obviously, I am instantiating my subview incorrectly. But where? I also must support iOS 9.1 and up.**

**SearchInputView.h**

```
 @interface SearchInputView : UIView
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textSearch;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSearch;
    @end
```

**SearchInputView.m**

```
@implementation SearchInputView
- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) customInit {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchInputView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
}

@end
```

Using the *Simulated Metrics*

[image]

And my **SearchInputViewController.m**

```
@interface SearchInputViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    SearchInputView * siv;
}

@end

@implementation SearchInputViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    siv = [[SearchInputView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:siv];

    siv.textSearch.delegate = self;
    [siv.lblMessage setHidden:true];
    [siv.indicator stopAnimating];
    [siv.btnSearch addTarget:self action:@selector(doSearch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try autolayout better

Add this to you class

```
+ (id) newFakeHUD
{
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SearchInputView" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *nibArray = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    SearchInputView*me = [nibArray objectAtIndex: 0];
    return me;
}
```

and in viewDidLoad

```
 re = [SearchInputView newFakeHUD]

 [self.view addSubview:re]

  re.frame = self.view.frame
```

OR

```
 -(void)viewDidLayoutsubviews()
{ 
  if(once)
  {
      once = NO;     

      self.siv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;   

      NSLayoutConstraint*con1=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.siv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];        

      NSLayoutConstraint*con2=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.siv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

      NSLayoutConstraint*con3=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.siv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];        

      NSLayoutConstraint*con4=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.siv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

      [self.view addConstraints:@[con1,con2,con3,con4]];

      [self.view.layoutIfNeeded]

    }

}
```

Comment: you should add the siv to self.view at viewDidload first